# Unix grep multiple patterns every hour

Tags: unix

Suppose, there are 4 different types of patterns(errors) in a log each may occur time to time. Eg: "timeout exception", "ldap error "," db error "," error four".  Can any one place provide me a script about:- how to grep multiple patterns in a log every hour and if the script finds the any pattern then it should send alert to me only once, no duplicate alerts. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code service factory, I am voting to mark this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    export ERRORS=`cat YOUR_LOG_FILE | grep -e "(timeout exception)|(ldap error)|(db error)|(error four)"
    if [ $ERRORS ]; then
        # sendmail or any other kind of "alert" you prefer.
        echo $ERRORS | sendmail "your@email.com"
    fi
    sleep 1h
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a crontab entry that will run once an hour. That entry can call your script:

```
logfile=/path/to/logfile/application.out

function send_alert {
   # Some sendmail or other tool to send your alert using the args
   printf "I want to alert about %s" "$*"
}

# Solution only announcing errors without sending them
grep -qE "timeout exception|ldap error|db error|error four" ${logfile} && 
        send_alert "grep found something"

# Solution sending number of errorlines
errorlinecount=$(grep -c "timeout exception|ldap error|db error|error four" )
if [ ${errorcount} -gt 0 ]; then
    send_alert "grep found ${errorcount} disturbing lines"
fi
```